# ccc4 Color List in COCOS2D

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-x

I'm looking for a tool or list that shows me different colours to the example below.

```
fillColor = ccc4(255, 0, 0,255);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want see the color that this code will generate ??

Comment: Try this [online tool](http://easycalculation.com/rgb-coder.php) for checking color.

Comment: Yes please? I would also like a tool or list where i can get other colours

Comment: http://www.workwithcolor.com/hsl-color-picker-01.htm

Comment: I don't understand this format though ccc4(255, 0, 0,255);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the online tools for it

1. [**ARGB Convertor**](http://www.netgfx.com/RGBaZR/)
2. [**List of colors**](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rgbtohex.htm)

**Update**

If you go through the docs `ccc4(255, 0, 0,255);` stands for
[**`ccc4(red,green,blue,opacity);`**](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/cc_types_8h.html#a664b22586e2357db8ed50dc6230cbcb2)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I have corrected that mistake..check updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this XCode plugin that lets you preview UIColor instances.
https://github.com/omz/ColorSense-for-Xcode

Comment: +1, Though it will not work for coco2d but still it's a good tool.

Answer (score 1):

Values are: red, green, blue and alpha (transparency) - in that order. Each value ranges from 0 (dark) to 255 (full brightness). Ignore alpha/transparency, it does not directly affect color.

You can use practically any image viewing or editing program that displays RGB values as either bytes (0-255) or hex codes (0x00 to 0xFF) to find out which values results in which color, and vice versa.

There are also plenty of RGB color charts on the web. Here's one [example with commonly used colors](http://www.tayloredmktg.com/rgb/).

Answer (score 1):

```
fillColor = ccc4(Red,Green,Blue,alpha);
```

Find that value using [Check Link](http://www.workwithcolor.com/hsl-color-picker-01.htm)